# LINQ expression to find if there are any matches between two arrays of string

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Suppose I have two lists of strings, `List1` and `list2`, where `List1` is a property of an object of type `Foo` in a list `fooList`.

I would like to remove a given `Foo` if no string in `foo.List1` matches any string in `list2` a la `RemoveAll`.

I can do this with nested for loops, but is there a way to do this with a single slick LINQ expression?

Long-winded code, building a new list rather than removing stuff from the existing list:

```
            var newFooList = new List<Foo>

            foreach (Foo f in fooList)
            {
                bool found = false;

                foreach (string s in newFooList)
                {
                    if (f.FooStringList.Contains(s))
                    {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (found)
                    newFooList.Add(f);
            }
```

Comment: In my opinion you should include long-winded code as it would communicate your desired behaviour better than your description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

```
var list2 = new List<string> { "one", "two", "four" };
var fooList = new List<Foo> {
    new Foo { List1 = new List<string> { "two", "three", "five" } },
    new Foo { List1 = new List<string> { "red", "blue" } }
};
fooList.RemoveAll( x => !x.List1.Intersect( list2 ).Any() );
Console.WriteLine( fooList );
```

Basically all the magic happens in `RemoveAll`: this only removes entries where the intersection of the entry's `List1` property and `list2` (i.e., the overlap) is empty.

I personally find the `!....Any()` construct kind of hard to read, so I like to have the following extension method on hand:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static bool Empty<T>( this IEnumerable<T> l, 
            Func<T,bool> predicate=null ) {
        return predicate==null ? !l.Any() : !l.Any( predicate );
    }
}
```

Then I can re-write the magic line in a way that's a little clearer:

```
fooList.RemoveAll( x => x.List1.Intersect( list2 ).Empty() );
```